# React-Admin List empty data placeholder not showed with "filterDefaultValues"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-admin

I have a List component with a custom component for "empty". Without filterDefaultValues, it shows it.

```
<List
      filters={DataFilters}
      filterDefaultValues={{ statuses: ['All'] }}
      empty={<NoData />}
```

it shows "No results found" but not my component

I want to have "filterDefaultValues" and "empty" working at the same time

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible using the base components. Indeed the idea is that react-admin will render the List when there are active filters, because it could be that there are no results because of the filters. So you need a way to be able to remove the filters to get some results back.
If you want to avoid this, you will need to implement your own List UI (you should still be able to use [ListBase](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ListBase.html) to get the contexts and controller from react-admin though).